# Operator = is not defined for type DBNull and Boolean, but no = operator is present

Tags: vb.net, boolean, operator-keyword, infragistics, dbnull

When checking the value of a checkbox style column in an UltraGrid, I'm using the following code in the BeforeRowsDeleted method, to set a boolean, and then depending on the boolean value, one of 2 delete methods is run.

However, I'm getting a system exception saying

> Operator = is not defined for type DBNull and Boolean

I've seen this error a few times before, but I'm confused because, although when stepping through the code I can see the value being stored is in fact a System.DBNull, there is no equals sign being used?

Why is this error occurring, and where is the code wrong?

```
If IsDBNull(ugProducts.ActiveRow.Cells("isNew").Value) Or _
            ugProducts.ActiveRow.Cells("isNew").Value = True Or _ 
            ugProducts.ActiveRow.Cells("isNew").Value = Nothing Then
        exProd = True
    Else
        exProd = False
    End If
```

I've also tried to set the value programmatically in the InitializeLayout method of the grid, but that didn't fix the situation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue lies in your conditions.

`IsDBNull(ugProducts.ActiveRow.Cells("isNew").Value)` evaluates to `-> True`

Then you try to do:

`ugProducts.ActiveRow.Cells("isNew").Value = True`

How can the above statement possibly be true if the value is `DBNull`? This is where the code is failing, because the `Value` is `DBNull` and you try to compare it to `True` (That's where the `=` is)

You need to short the condition using `OrElse` if it is `DBNull`:

```
If IsDBNull(ugProducts.ActiveRow.Cells("isNew").Value) OrElse _
```

If it is `DBNull` then it won't attempt to do the other comparisons, and will enter the block straight away.